# Can multiple Wii balance boards be used at the same time?

Tags: nintendo-wii

One online shop offers two Wii balance boards as a package, but I found information on wiki that two balance boards cannot be used at the same time.

So, is there a reason why they offer two Wii balance boards in a package? Are there any multiplayer games for the Wii balance board? **Can multiple Wii balance boards be used at the same time?**

Comment: Wii Punch-out has a multiplayer mode, but only supports balance board in single player. :(

Comment: I've edited the title and question body to not sound like a recommendation question, hopefully this will make this question suitable for reopening.

Answer (score 6):

There are currently no games supporting multiple Balance boards, and I don't expect there to be any, if only for the price of the devices, and the amount of space needed for such a setup.

All current games supporting multiplayer with a single balanceboard do so in a hot-seat style. (or should I say hot-board)

Technically, for as far as I can see, the Wii itself is perfectly capable of supporting multiple balance boards, but I don't know if this functionality is even availble for developpers

Comment: I'll hold my breath for _Twister_ on Wii.  :P

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is technically possible to have a multiplayer game where both players use their own balance board.

I sadly can't recall where I read this (it's been a while), but I believe that internally a balance board is seen by the Wii as multiple controllers (maybe 2-3 per board). Since the Wii can only handle up to 4 controllers at a time, there aren't enough "slots" to support multiple balance boards.

The reason that Punch-out can't do multiplayer with balance boards is that if the balance board takes up two controller slots, and then the Wiimote/nunchuck takes up another, that's 3 controllers for one player.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii) - "Up to 16 Wii Remote controllers (10 in Standard Mode, 6 in One Time Mode, connected wirelessly via Bluetooth)"

Comment: The Wii detects the Balance Board as a single Wiimote with a balance board extension, only taking one slot.

Comment: I stand corrected, then. :)